# Problem in append query in MS ACCESS sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using MS Access. I have written this query...

```
INSERT INTO survey1 ( [Coach No] )
SELECT pvc1.[Coach No]
FROM pvc1 LEFT JOIN survey1 ON pvc1.[Coach No]=survey1.[Coach No]
WHERE (((survey1.[Coach No]) Is Null));
```

BUT it is not appending data in my table survey1...

Comment: are you getting an error message?

Comment: while running query it is saying that it can't append due to KEY VIOLATIONS. But I am not able to figure out which key violations?

Answer (score 2):

Break the query up.  Does just the select return any results?

```
SELECT pvc1.[Coach No]
FROM pvc1 LEFT JOIN survey1 ON pvc1.[Coach No]=survey1.[Coach No]
WHERE (((survey1.[Coach No]) Is Null))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't make sense. You are joining on `NULL`, then you try to insert that `NULL` into a table as a PK where it originally came from. You are joining with `survey1` on `Coach No` and are trying to insert the `Coach No` back into `survey1`  What are you trying to do here?

**Update** now that OP elaborated on what he wants to do:

```
INSERT INTO survey1 ( [Coach No] )
SELECT pvc1.[Coach No]
FROM pvc1 
WHERE pvc1.[Coach No] NOT IN (SELECT [Coach No] FROM survey1 WHERE NOT [Coach No] IS NULL)
```

Comment: Actually I want to make a query to add [Coach No] from [pvc1] that are not in [survey1].

Comment: It is selecting those [Coach No] in datasheet view but do not append it when I run it. When it is run it gives error message like it can't append due to some KEY VIOLATIONS.

Comment: Ok, is this a foreign key tzo some other table?

Comment: [Coach No] is a primary key in both the tables [pvc1] and [survey1].

Comment: And it's not a foreign key to some other PK?